# Is this function of a matrix convex?

Tags: matrices, convexity, eigenvector, norms

Let $\mathcal{N}_{n}$ be the set of symmetric nonnegative irreducible matrices. For a matrix $A \in \mathcal{N}_{n}$ let $v^{A}$ be its [Perron vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Perron.E2.80.93Frobenius_theorem_for_irreducible_matrices), normalized so that $||v^{A}||_{2}=1$.

Define the function $f:\mathcal{N}_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(A)=||v^{A}||_{1}.
$$

> According to my observations, $f$ is apparently convex.

Is this true/known?

Comment: What's the Perron vector?

Comment: @DeaneYang It's the positive eigenvector corresponding to the spectral radius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I am misinterpreting something, because according to my experiments, this function is **neither** convex nor concave.

The following is a counterexample (**EDIT:** I changed the example to use symmetric matrices):

\begin{equation*}
A=\begin{pmatrix}8 &4\\ 4 & 6\end{pmatrix},\quad B=\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 4\\ 4 & 6\end{pmatrix},\quad C=\frac{A+B}{2}=\begin{pmatrix}6 & 4\\ 4 &6 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
For this choice, we have

\begin{equation*}
v(A) = (.7882, .6154),\quad v(B)=(.6154,.7882),\quad v(C)=(.7071, .7071).
\end{equation*}
But $\|v(C)\|_1 > 0.5\|v(A)\|_1 + 0.5\|v(B)\|_1$ (notice all there vectors have unit 2-norm as required).

A similar counterexample to potential concavity is also easy to find.

**EDIT 2:** Here is a counterexample to concavity.

\begin{equation*}
  A = \begin{pmatrix}16&2\\ 2&16\end{pmatrix},\quad B = \begin{pmatrix}14&8\\8 &2 \end{pmatrix},\quad C = (A+B)/2
\end{equation*}
Then, we have
\begin{equation*}
  v(A) =  \begin{pmatrix}\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix},\quad v(B) =\begin{pmatrix}\tfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\\\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\end{pmatrix},\quad v(C)=  \begin{pmatrix}\tfrac{3+\sqrt{34}}{\sqrt{68+6 \sqrt{34}}}\\\tfrac{5}{\sqrt{68+6 \sqrt{34}}}  \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
Doing the numerics with this shows that $\|v(C)\|_1-0.5(\|v(A)\|_1+\|v(B)\|_1) = -0.0150285...$.

Comment: But $A$ is not symmetric (the question requires symmetric matrices)

Comment: @Suresh: thanks; changed example to use symmetric $A$; the claim still fails. Maybe Felix had something else in mind...

Comment: Actually, I've been getting $\|v(C)\|_1 > 0.5\|v(A)\|_1 + 0.5\|v(B)\|_1$ all the time (which is of course concave, not convex, silly me). Are you sure you can produce examples of the opposite kind? I'm unable to replicate them...

Comment: @Felix: it was an attractive conjecture. A related geometric convexity does hold though for Perron vectors (but under a rather special situation): see here: http://www.ams.org/proc/1993-118-04/S0002-9939-1993-1139482-5/S0002-9939-1993-1139482-5.pdf